How can I draw a line extending perpendicularly out of an xy canvas plane in tikz?
How can I draw a line extending perpendicularly out of an xy canvas plane in tikz?
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        tdplot_main_coords
        ,canvas is xy plane at z=3
    ]
        \draw[step=0.2] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
        \draw[red, ultra thick] (0,0) -- (0,0,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Do you actually need canvas is .. plane at . here? It should be possible to just use xyz coordinates all over your example.

@JasperHabicht In my actual document, I set x, y and z differently. I chose this MWE because it was simpler than calculating all of the coordinates.

I don't know your set-up, but if you restrict the application of canvas is xy plane at z=3 to the grid only (by using \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=3] ... \end{scope}), it should work. (Which makes sense actually, as the perpendicular line is not on the xy canvas but sticks out of it.)

Since a perpendicular line by definition is not on the same plane from which it sticks out or which it intersects, you might want to restrict the application of canvas is xy plane at z=3 to the grid only:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        tdplot_main_coords
    ]
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=3]
            \draw[step=0.2] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
        \end{scope}
        \draw[red, ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


If you want to connect coordinates on the plane and the line, you can define a coordinate within the scope and refer to it from outside the scope. In this case, (-1,-1) in the plane is (-1,-1,3) in the outer scope as we set canvas is xy plane at z=3:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        tdplot_main_coords,
        pin distance=1cm,
    ]
        \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=3]
            \draw[step=0.2] (-2,-2) grid (2,2);
            \coordinate (a) at (-1,-1);
            \node[inner sep=0pt, pin={90:{$(-1,-1,3)$}}] at (a) {};
        \end{scope}
        \draw[red, ultra thick] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3);
        \draw[blue] (a) to[bend right] (0,0,0.5);
        \node[inner sep=0pt, pin={0:{$(0,0,\frac{1}{2})$}}] at (0,0,0.5) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



This works for this case, but I am curious how to get it to use the coordinates in the plane. For instance, (1,0) in the plane is different that (1,0) in the tikzpicture. For this particular plane, it is easy to find the coordinates, but for others, it is not so easy. I may post another question about it tomorrow. For now, I will accept this answer.

@Jasper you probably can define a coordinate in the plane which will then be accessible from outside the scope

+1. Just for extra information: The canvas is xy plane at z can also be an option directly to \draw.

@Jasper Actually, (1,0) in the plane is the same as (1,0,3)̀  in the tikzpicture(which is because you setcanvas is xy plane at z=3` obviously). So, refering to coordinates is not too complicated at least in this case.

@JasperHabicht I tried defining a coordinate in the plane, but it did not maintain its position after leaving the scope.

@Jasper It should though! Maybe you can show an example where the coordinate does not keep its position.

@JasperHabicht ahhh, I was defining the coordinate after \pgflowlevelsynccm. I can do this in any plane now. Thanks!
